# jmeter request recording with proxy does not create samplers

Tags: java, windows, jmeter

I am trying do this example recording tutorial http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf

What does not work is that jmeter creates the samplers under the "recording controller" node. But I can see that it is recording, because there are records in the "view result tree" node.

In the terminal there aren't shown any errors.

I am starting to get frustrated because I think I did it all right (yea i know i am probably wrong ;) )

I am running it under windows with jre7.

Hopefully somebody knows what could go wrong there. Because it is the first time I try this out I realy don't know what to look for :/

Thanks already!

Comment: ok strange, i found out that in this tutorial are two different patterns entered in the http(s) test script recorder. in the text they say to enter ".*\.html" but in the image there is "*\.html". none of these worked for me. but if i leave it empty it works ... i don't get it :/ ... i think it should be the first pattern because it looks like an regular expression

Comment: I found out that it starts creating the requests if I leave it blank, but I still would like to specify the resources that it should record/request.

Comment: I had the same problem, I think the docs are not right or old.  But a blank filter worked for me too.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See :

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP%28S%29_Test_Script_Recorder

Show you recorder configuration, your issue comes as your comments seem to say from exclusion/inclusion pattern.

See a typical configuration to exclude images, css and javascript files:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you try starting your jmeter like,

Jmeter -H "proxy" -P "port" -u "username" -a "password"

username and password are optional i.e. it depends on proxy.

and after then try recording your script by making network settings to localhost. 
This will listen everything between your machine and proxy.